# Difference between ACM's print and online memberships

Tags: journals

I would like to inquire about the difference between ACM's SIGACT online membership and print membership.

The group's main page showing both of the membership choices
https://www.acm.org/special-interest-groups/sigs/sigact

Background:
I am a sophomore computer science student interested in computing topics with emphasis on mathematical rigor, particularly, computational complexity theory and quantum computing. Subscribing to prestigious ACM gaining latest developments in the field and a chance of connecting to others seems promising.

Comment: Have you checked whether your university library already carries these journals?  You might not need to subscribe to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACM SIGs (Special Interest Groups) generally publish things like conference proceedings and newsletters. A print subscription implies that they are sent to you in print, usually a few times a year. An online subscription gives you access to the same materials only online with a login. Other than that, the memberships are the same.

Comment: I have received an official e-mail from ACM confirming your reply:

Dear Mustafa,
Thank you for contacting us at ACM.  My name is Nancy and I will be happy to assist you today.
SIGACT Membership includes a quarterly newsletter SIGACT News. The only different is that you get this newsletter in print for the SIGACT print membership and it’s online only for the SIGACT online membership. All other membership benefits are the same.
If you have further questions and/or comments, please do not hesitate to contact me.  Have a wonderful day!